# spacy: list index out of range

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I encountered "**list index out of range**" error when running **nlp(text_1)** with spacy. However, **no issue on text_2** (similar to text_1, except sentences 1 and 2 are joined as one). This is my code:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
nlp.add_pipe("entityLinker", last=True)
```

```
text_1 = """
Those parts were designed by Massimiliano Siccardi, with original music by Luca Longobardi.
The show's arrival in New York comes as the city emerges from a lockdown that shut down cultural events and art crowds.
'I feel like this is a huge, bright beacon of hope for arts in New York.' said Korins.
"""
text_1 = contractions.fix(unidecode(text_1)).strip()
nlp(text_1)
```

```
text_2 = """
Those parts were designed by Massimiliano Siccardi, with original music by Luca Longobardi.The show's arrival in New York comes as the city emerges from a lockdown that shut down cultural events and art crowds.
'I feel like this is a huge, bright beacon of hope for arts in New York.' said Korins.
"""
text_2 = contractions.fix(unidecode(text_2)).strip()
nlp(text_2)
```

May I know if anyone can help to explain? Thanks.

Comment: Please post the error as a text ,not an image.

Comment: The code looks incomplete since it uses a variable named `text` but no declaration.

Comment: try removing the `’` character from `text_1` and test please

Comment: Yes, I have removed both `'` and the error is still the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by removing '\n':

```
text_1 = contractions.fix(unidecode(text_1)).strip().replace('\n', '')
```

Thanks, everyone for your suggestions.